# (Embedded?) Ruby/Python, existing XAMPP stack

Tags: python, ruby, xampp

I've been plugging away for about a year and a bit now with PHP on my local XAMPP install. I've learned very much, but am now needing to expand my knowledge base with concern to other languages.

So, I figured I'd try tackling Ruby/Python.

Now, since I'm sticking to web application development, I would assume embedded Ruby/Python would be the way to go, transitionally, moving from PHP.

I have an existing XAMPP install on my Windows 7 x64 machine, which I'd like to pile Ruby and Python on top of. However, I'm a bit confused with how to do this (*read, if I can do this*)

I want to move to the newer XAMPP release (to 1.7.4 from... whatever I'm running) anyways, and I've downloaded the RubyInstaller 1.9.2, but I figured I'd ask for some insight before I go and break something.

So, how do I go about configuring a XAMPP install to support embedded Ruby/Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just install ruby and python, and then use [mod_rails](http://www.modrails.com/) and [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)?  I do the same thing on my local machine (MacOS, though) and it works great - never tried it through XAMPP though.  Some people have had luck with MAMP but it's a pain due to how they distribute it - you may have better luck with XAMPP.  In this particular case, though, I wouldn't be too worried about breaking anything - at most, you'll compile a bad mod_wsgi module and throw it away.

Comment: **Thanks mway;** It appears I have a bit to learn about Apache configuration before I get this up and running.

Comment: Sure thing - mod_rails is very simple to implement after you install ruby/rubygems and install the rails (etc) gems; mod_wsgi is a bit trickier but using the python and mod_wsgi docs (and google) you should be able to figure it out.  The best way to learn is to try locally.

Comment: Passenger aka mod_rails does not run on Windows, btw.

Comment: @phoffer Too true - thanks for pointing that out, I should have mentioned that.  @TomcatExodus If you're running this on a Windows box, then, you'll want to look around for setups involving having Apache serve Rails apps with mongrel via apache + mod_rewrite - there are plenty of docs and examples if you just do a Google search for something like "rails apache mongrel".  HTH!

Comment: @TomcatExodus There are also other methods - mongrel is probably the simplest, but in a real environment you'd likely want to have either a load balancer or apache proxying to a separate service (like lighttpd via fcgi).